# change h2 database creation location using java

Tags: java, h2

```
I tried to create a h2 database using Java. the following coding are working fine. 

    public static Connection conn;
    static String dbName = "check";
    static String className = "org.h2.Driver";
    static String url = "jdbc:h2:~/" + dbName;
public static Connection getConnection() {
        if (conn == null) {
        Class.forName(className);
                    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "sa", "sa");
```

database created at C location. But i except data should be create at other Drive.

Answer (score 2):

The ~ symbol in the path refers to your home folder. If you want a separate drive you'll have to indicate the absolute path. But that's not a very portable solution though.

Use for instance

static String url = "jdbc:h2:d:/" + dbName;

Comment: Great to hear @Bass. Can you go ahead and accept this as the right answer?

Comment: I have another one Doubt in H2 data base.. h2 jar file weight-age. not h2 database..  Storage capacity?